# Ionic app not makes http requests

Tags: ionic-framework

I developed an app with Ionic v1 and tested with "ionic serve" and "ionic run android" and works fine. It makes all $http requests to an external API (that allows CORS) and I recive the data well.

The probleme comes when I try to test the app in real mode. I added the app to Ionic view to test in Android mobile device and I see that the requests to the API are not performed (because I not see any data printed in tha app).

For what reasons can be? I need to perform extra configs in my API server? I need to perform some special configs to Ionic app?

PD: I installed cordova withelist plugin and added this lines to config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You verify if Cordova CLI has generated these Android permissions entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I hope that helps.

Greetings.

Comment: Hello. I see that only I have the first line: 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
and I added the second manually:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
But the problem persists

Comment: Marc, what version of Cordova you have?

Comment: cordva -v returns me 6.4.0

Comment: Have you installed the plugin ```cordova-plugin-whitelist``` in your project? Other thing, have you added on your index file the following tag? [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy)

Comment: Yes, I installed the plugin and I added in index.html this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Comment: Do you try to debug using the emulator provided by Android? On the log maybe you can view the error.

Comment: Hello. I opened the app trought Android emulator en I copied all entries of the logcat in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/D04kJBnS This pastebin is the log since I i open the app and I navigate to a section that should do an API request. I not see any request.